# JSF2 File Not Found Exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, filenotfoundexception

Getting a strange error.

I have a few different files in `WebContent`.

```
WebContent/page1.xhtml
WebContent/page2.xhtml
WebContent/page3.xhtml
```

I have my web.xml set up like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/01/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/02/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/03/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/04/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When running the web server (JBoss EAP 6.1), I can get to `/myapp/01/page1.xhtml`, `/myapp/01/page2.xhtml`, etc. This seems to be the case for everything except for `/myapp/03/`.

For `/myapp/03/`, I can get to `page2.xhtml` just fine, but when I try to get to `page1.xhtml` I am getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I can get to `page1.xhtml` just fine from all of the other combinations (`/myapp/01/`, `/myapp/02/`, `/myapp/04/`, etc. all the way to 10).

All of the `/myapp/##/` stuff goes through the same filter, and the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is happening when the `chain.doFilter()` method is called, but it works fine for all of the other sections, so I don't know if it could be in there or not.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was a path error. The site was set up to use multiple include files, some of the paths for which were set via code. I needed to review every path to ensure that the correct files were being found.